# Stripe connected_account linked his own customer ( for subscription )

Tags: stripe-payments, subscription

I'm trying to anderstand how the relation between connected account and his own customer, which have subscribe ( "create subscriptions to charge your connected accounts a fee for using your platform." )
It's this case in the Stripe documentation : https://stripe.com/docs/connect/subscriptions#create-a-customer-object-to-represent-the-connected-account

I can create a customer, but I don't see how I can link it to the my connected account.

In the end, what I want is that the connected account can access to his subscription infos ( invoice, payment methods, etc.. ) direcltly via his Stripe connected account dashboard. But maybe I can't have this ?

I try my luck with Stripe support, but it seems they don't anderstand what I want to do, so I try my luck here.

Thanks !

I tried to see where in Stripe platform dashboard I can create such a customer linked to the connected account, but can't firgure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an object on the Connected account using Stripe's Connect [Account Header](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/authentication). For instance, your code would look something like the following for creating the customer on the Connected Account using the [Create a customer API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/create):

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/customers \
  -u "sk_test_:" \
  -H "Stripe-Account: {{CONNECTED_ACCOUNT_ID}}" \
  --data-urlencode email="person@example.com"
```

I do not think you can create a customer object on your Connected Account using your Platform account's Dashboard.

Comment: As I anderstand, this will create a customer as a customer FOR the connected account, not as a customer REPRESENTING the connected account.  
Moreover, this is documented for retrieving customers, not creation..
I'll give a try anyway. Thx.